# Navigate on touch or scroll when content is fixed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add scrolling navigation to a presentation style landing page in **React** and **GatsbyJS**.

The issue lies in that I cannot where each page(slide) is `fixed` at `100%` height and no scrolling occurs.

As you can see from the below code, the `keydown` listener navigates using the down arrow, but how can I achieve the same action from a mousewheel, scroll, touchpad or swipe down?

```
class Index extends Component {
  NEXT = 40;

  swipeUp = () => {
    this.navigate({ keyCode: this.NEXT });
  };

  navigate = ({ keyCode }) => {
    if (keyCode === this.NEXT) {
      navigate(ROUTES.SLIDE2);
    }
    return false;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', this.navigate);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.navigate);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PageContent>
        <PageContainer />
      </PageContent>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR https://codepen.io/devanshj/pen/RvmMpM

1. For the wheel part, you are correct that `scroll` event won't fire (because there's no content overflowing as the pages are `position: fixed`). But the [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event will fire regardless. And then we can use the `wheelDelta` from the wheel event to get the direction of the scrolling.
2. For the swipe part, our problem could have been solved if we had some stuff scrolling and user swiping would fire an `scroll` event. But that's not the case. In our case we'll have to figure out swipe event from events like `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend`. There's a 7kb library called [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) that does all that stuff and we can simply listen to events like `swipeup`.
3. You have not provided an appropriate sample to reproduce the problem, so I have made a basic sample [here](https://codepen.io/devanshj/pen/RvmMpM) (same as above link). I have not used react because it's irrelevant to the problem, you can implement this is your react app too. (If you can't, provide the react sample and I'll help you out but imo it won't be too hard)

Comment: Thanks. Hammer.js looks like the solution to my problem here. No worries implementing into React, although the sample you provided doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: @Darren You're welcome! There was a typo was typo in the code that I fixed a few minutes ago... Can you recheck? Because it's working for me... If it still doesn't work can you tell which part is not working or what's happening so that I can debug...

Comment: @Darren No problem! :)

Comment: Quick question, with `document.addEventListener('wheel', ({ wheelDelta })` how would one slow this to fire only once at a time?

Comment: @Darren you can pass the listener function is a denouncer form lodash or something like that... Eg `document.addEventListener("wheel", ({ wheelDelta }) => _.debounce(() => { /* listener */ }, 500))` I haven't tried it but this should work...

Comment: @Darren You also might want to pass `{ leading: true }` as third argument to make it work exactly like you want...

Answer (score 0):

React supports following events and you can use them in similar manner to keydown

- mousewheel : use `onWheel` event
- scroll : use `onScroll` event
- touchpad : use `onTouchCancel onTouchEnd onTouchMove onTouchStart`

more list of events is here : https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#touch-events

Comment: Thank you Shadab but my issue is in using these elements in a `fixed` height of `100vh`. No condition can be set to identify the `event`

Comment: Can you once check by adding `overflow:auto` to your body tag and then attach the onwheel and onscroll event